# Hide bottom message when open new file

Tags: startup, message

As title, is there any options in vim that can do that?

Need a way to control messages system in vim, and as usual even hard-coded, still need preserve some options for users.

Comment: What message exactly are you trying to hide? I also don't follow your second sentence ("need preserve some optins for users")?

Comment: When I try to open a new file, an absolute path of that file will appear at command bar, I'd like it to be hiden. I've found that `F` in shortmess options do the things. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You should add that as an answer, instead of an edit. It's fine to answer your own question :-)

Answer (score 2):

as suggested by Carpetsmoker in comments, here is how I solved this:

```
set shortmess+=F
```